# Accessing variables in js from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am playing around with a website in which 8 triangles make an octagon and when the user mouses over each triangle it moves 20px away from the center of the triangle. Currently my JS looks like this:

```
//pushes out the top triangle
$('#top').hover(
    if($(this).css('moving'){
        function(){
            $(this).animate({top:"-=20px"}, 'slow');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({top:"+=20px"}, 'slow');
        });
    }
```

However I don't want to have to enter the -20px for each triangle. I was actually thinking that if the each div stored the directions it needs to move, then the code could look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//pushes out the triangle the user is hovering over
$(this).hover(  
        function(){
        $(this).animate({top: this.up}, speed);
                    $(this).animate({right: this.right}, speed);
    },
            function(){
                $(this).animate({top: this.down}, speed);
                    $(this).animate({right: this.left}, speed);
    }
);}
```

Where each div would have the variables up, down, left, and right. For example, the top triangle would have the values:

```
top.up= "-=20px"
top.down= "+=20px"
top.left= "+=0px"
top.right= "+=0px"
```

EDIT:
After making the changes suggested below this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//  if(stationary){
//      stationary=false;
    $("div").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({top: this.data('up') }, "slow");
            $(this).animate({right: this.data('right') }, speed);
        }
    ),
        function(){
            $(this).animate({top: this.data('down') }, speed);
            $(this).animate({right: this.data('left') }, speed);
//              stationary=true;
        }
    );

}
```

This doesn't move the div's. Also I added in a var stationary so that a div can only move if no divs are currently moving.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle so we can see the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

You could use the `data` property:

`<div data-top-up="-=20px"></div>`

And the use it like this:

`.animate({top: this.data('top-up') }, speed)`

Comment: 30 seconds from posting almost the same answer, this seems like the most reasonable solution without more info.

Comment: True, more info would help ;)

Comment: I just tried this and its not working, my code is in the main post

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle.com?